# Server Object Extension MultiPoint Input

Tags: json, array, server-object-extension

I have soe which accepts {x:-112,y:35} as input parameter.
how can I modify the soe code so that I can pass more than one point as my input parameters like
{x:-112,y:35},{x:-113,36},{x:-113.5,y:34} and so on
Thanks!

Comment: What GIS software and version are you wanting to use to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about a SOE for ArcGIS Server? If so, what version? What is your development language? You need to provide more information before we can answer this question.

Comment: yes, SOE for ArcGIS Server, 10.2 Development language is c# .net I want to modify the existing FindNearFeature esri sample to accept more than one point. where do I change in the code so that it accepts more than one set of x,y?

Answer (score 1):

To start, you should use the esri json featureset spec which includes properties for geometry and attributes.

```
{
    "features" : [
{
    "geometry" : {"x" : -104.44, "y" : 34.83},
    "attributes" : {"Id" : 43, "Name" : "Feature 1"}
},
{
     "geometry" : {"x" : -100.65, "y" : 33.69},
     "attributes" : {"Id" : 67, "Name" : "Feature 2"}
}
]
}
```

The first thing you'll want to do is convert it to IGeometry. If your using C#, you may find this this NicoGIS favorite helpful for converting a json geometry to IGeometry.  http://nicogis.blogspot.com/search/label/SOE

```
public IGeometry ConvertAnyJsonGeometry(JsonObject jsonObjectGeometry)
    {
        object[] objArray;

        if (jsonObjectGeometry.TryGetArray("rings", out objArray))
        {
            return Conversion.ToGeometry(jsonObjectGeometry, esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon);
        }

        if (jsonObjectGeometry.TryGetArray("paths", out objArray))
        {
            return Conversion.ToGeometry(jsonObjectGeometry, esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline);
        }

        if (jsonObjectGeometry.TryGetArray("points", out objArray))
        {
            return Conversion.ToGeometry(jsonObjectGeometry, esriGeometryType.esriGeometryMultipoint);
        }

        try
        {
            return Conversion.ToGeometry(jsonObjectGeometry, esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint);
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                return Conversion.ToGeometry(jsonObjectGeometry, esriGeometryType.esriGeometryEnvelope);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I included this one in an SOE post with some other helpful SOE snippets:
http://bcdcspatial.blogspot.com/search/label/Server%20Object%20Extensions

Comment: right now the way it is, the format is {"x" : -113, "y" : 37} If I just add {Geometry:{{"x" : -113, "y" : 37},{"x" : -109, "y" : 37}}, then it errors out. the json string looks like this "{\"x\":-113,\"y\":37}", it ignores the second set of x and y values. My soe is similar to FindNearFeatures samples provided by esri. I am trying to modify it to accept more than single set x,y value.

Comment: what is the error?